# Row with 2 children, one column and one image layout in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

### EDIT

Its cutting off my background gradient and not showing the image.

[image: screenshot]

I need to have a layout in flutter with a column of text objects to the left and an image to the right. I found an example picture on the flutter.io site but they dont show the code for this particular example. I have the column of data formatted but cant figure out how to add the image to the right.

Here is the picture of what I am trying to get layout wise.

[image: Layout]

Here is my existing code with the data we want to the right of the image

```
    class MemberProfile extends StatelessWidget {
   @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
    appBar:  LBAppBar().getAppBar(),
    drawer:  LBDrawer().getDrawer(),
     body: 
      Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            colors: [Color.fromRGBO(1, 89, 99, 1.0), Colors.grey],
            begin: Alignment.bottomLeft,
            end: Alignment.topRight,
          ),
        ),
        child:     
         Container(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0, bottom: 10.0, left: 20.0),
                child: Text("Name : Sam Cromer",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white70,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 19.0)),
              ),
              Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0, bottom: 10.0, left: 20.0),
                  child: Text("Sex : Male",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white70,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 19.0))),
              Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0, bottom: 10.0, left: 20.0),
                  child: Text("Age : 42",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white70,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 19.0))),
              Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0, bottom: 10.0, left: 20.0),
                  child: Text("Status : Divorced",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white70,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 19.0))),
              Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0, bottom: 10.0, left: 20.0),
                  child: Text("Trumatic Event : ",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white70,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 19.0))),
              Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0, bottom: 10.0, left: 20.0),
                  child: Text("Motorcycle Accident July 2005, TBI",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white70,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 19.0))),
              Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0, bottom: 10.0, left: 20.0),
                  child: Text("Bio :",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white70,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 19.0))),
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                    left: 30.0, top: 150.0, bottom: 30.0, right: 30.0),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                      child: OutlineButton(
                        child: Text('Offer support'),
                        textColor: Colors.white,
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
                        onPressed: () {
                          // Navigator.of(context).push( MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) =>  CheckInQ()));
                        },
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),

        ),
        //here
      ),

);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';



class MemberProfile extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Scaffold(
 body: Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      gradient: LinearGradient(
        colors: [Color.fromRGBO(1, 89, 99, 1.0), Colors.grey],
        begin: Alignment.bottomLeft,
        end: Alignment.topRight,
      ),
    ),
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
    //height: 1500.0,
    child: Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget> [
          Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[

              Text("Name : Sam Cromer",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white70,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 19.0)),

              Text("Sex : Male",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white70,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 19.0)),
              Text("Age : 42",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white70,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 19.0)),
              Text("Status : Divorced",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white70,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 19.0)),
              Text("Event : Motorcycle",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white70,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 19.0)),
              Text("Bio :",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white70,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 19.0)),
                       Text("Bio :",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white70,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 19.0)),
                       Text("Bio :",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white70,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 19.0)),
                       Text("Bio :",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white70,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 19.0)),

            ],
          ),
          Column(
            children: <Widget>[

              SizedBox(
                width: 200.0,
                height: 200.0,
                child: Image.asset('lib/img/darth-vader_small.jpg'),  // Your image widget here
              ),

            ],
          ),
        ]
    ),
      ),
   );
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the your `MemberProfile` class modified to contain one custom row laid out as the above image:

```
     class MemberProfile extends StatelessWidget {
     @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return Scaffold(
     body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            colors: [Color.fromRGBO(1, 89, 99, 1.0), Colors.grey],
            begin: Alignment.bottomLeft,
            end: Alignment.topRight,
          ),
        ),
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: 200.0,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget> [
              Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: <Widget>[

                  Text("Name : Sam Cromer",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white70,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 19.0)),

                  Text("Sex : Male",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white70,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 19.0)),
                  Text("Age : 42",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white70,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 19.0)),
                  Text("Status : Divorced",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white70,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 19.0)),
                  Text("Trumatic Event : ",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white70,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 19.0)),
                  Text("Motorcycle ",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white70,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 19.0)),
                  Text("Bio :",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white70,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 19.0)),

                ],
              ),
              Column(
                children: <Widget>[

                  SizedBox(
                    width: 200.0,
                    height: 200.0,
                    child: Image.asset('assets/images/test.jpg'), // Your image widget here
                  ),

                ],
              ),
            ]
        ),
      ),
   );
 }
```

}

the code given here limits the `height` of the row to `200.0` so the size of the image doesn't distort the total layout of the row , you can opt for an alternative approach by placing the `Image` widget into a `SizedBox` with fixed `width` and `height`.

The reason the `gradient` was `cut off` is because it's applied in the parent `Container` and containers by [definition](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Container-class.html) "size themselves to the size of their children", so if you want your "gradient effect" to fill the full screen you have to set an explicit `width` and `height`:

```
   body: 
  Container(
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
```

Comment: I plugged in your code and am editing my question to show you what Im seeing.

Comment: Image doesnt show up and its cutting off my gradient background

Comment: I did't find where you put your `Image` widget so I can't tell what is causing the issue

Comment: I put it in your code example. It doesnt show up, the screenshot is what the result is.

Comment: Column(
                children: <Widget>[

                  SizedBox(
                    width: 200.0,
                    height: 200.0,
                    child: Image.asset('assets/images/test.jpg'), // Your image widget here
                  ),

                ],
              ),

Comment: You have to use your own image, or if you don't have one use this line instead of `Image.asset`: Image.network(
  'https://picsum.photos/250?image=9',
)

Comment: Can you send a screenshot of what u see when u run it ? I get the background gradient cut off and no image even when I pull in one I use elsewhere in my app

Comment: i found an error on this while debugging:  I/flutter ( 4595): Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI file:///picsum.photos/250?image=9

Comment: I fixed the background and image issue I'l post the code. Thanks for the help!